# Which characters are allowed in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis queue names?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Couldn't find any documentation about which characters are allowed in queue names for Apache ActiveMQ Artemis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no restrictions on what characters are allowed in queue names in ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Do you have any reference to this information?

Comment: I'm an ActiveMQ committer, and I'm familiar with the [source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis).